# Background on java being pushed around

Tags: java, swing, jlabel

So I am currently working on a project for something. Basically, right now I have two buttons, two text labels that change when you click a button, and then there is the background. The issue with the background is that its not staying where it should. The buttons/ labels are at the top, and the background is pushed below everything. If I remove the buttons/label the background fills the whole program. Here is some of the code:

```
ImageIcon backg = new ImageIcon(getClass().getResource("grastri.png"));
background = new JLabel(backg);
add(background);
background.setAlignmentX(CENTER_ALIGNMENT);
background.setAlignmentY(CENTER_ALIGNMENT);
```

If anyone is able to help, that would be great!

Comment: You might have to call Repaint when the window is painted.

Comment: This sounds like normal layout behavior. Are you using a layout? In general a JLabel cannot have things on top of it. http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/visual.html

Answer (score 2):

Your background is in a JLabel which is being added to your GUI. If you want the background to be behind all, then either make a JPanel your main container and draw the image in the JPanel's `paintComponent(Graphics g)` method or make the JLabel that holds the image the main container (but give it a layout and make it opaque first).